# How do i set a temp variable to a value based from another table

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I am using the AdventureWorks 2012 database and I'm absolutely stumped on this one,

So far I have

```
alter proc pName
(
@TranID int
)
as
declare @AccountID int
declare @Entered datetime
declare @Type char
declare @Amount money
declare @Service money
declare @WithdrawalDecrease smallint
declare @WithdrawalCount smallint

set @AccountID = (select AccountID 
                  from Transactions
                  where TransID = @TranID)

set @WithdrawalCount = (select WithdrawalCount 
                        from Accounts
                        inner join Transactions on Transactions.AccountID = Accounts.AccountID
                        where Transactions.AccountID = @AccountID)
```

But the variable taking the value what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem?  Are you getting an error?  Is the value you're receiving not what you're expecting?  We need something to work off of.

Comment: The variable wont take a value no errors just empty value

Comment: How many are returned for this statement "select AccountID from Transactions where TransID = @TranID"

Comment: I get 1, value of 7 in and AccountID = 2

Comment: Can u be bit more clear i didn't get the last comment

Comment: I only get 1 value returned

@transID = 7
(returned value is -- Account ID = 2)

Comment: Okay.. but 2 is not assigned to @AccountID???

Comment: Check where AccountID = 2 is present on Transactions table

Comment: it was being assigned to @account ID sorry, I didn't realise how unclear that was, the variable that wasn't taking was the @ withdrawal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the syntax

```
SET @AccountID = (SELECT AccountID
                  FROM   Transactions
                  WHERE  TransID = @TranID)
SET @WithdrawalCount = (SELECT WithdrawalCount
                        FROM   Accounts
                               INNER JOIN Transactions
                                       ON Transactions.AccountID = Accounts.AccountID
                        WHERE  Transactions.AccountID = @AccountID)
```

But here you are trying to set AccountID to @AccountID for TransID =@TranID. If your Transactions table has more than one row for @TranID then the last inserted value  will be assigned to the variable
so try using `top 1` with `order by`

```
SET @AccountID = (SELECT top 1 AccountID
                  FROM   Transactions
                  WHERE  TransID = @TranID order by column)

SET @WithdrawalCount = (SELECT top 1 WithdrawalCount
                        FROM   Accounts
                               INNER JOIN Transactions
                                       ON Transactions.AccountID = Accounts.AccountID
                        WHERE  Transactions.AccountID = @AccountID order by column)
```