# SQL Server select (top) two rows into two temp variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a query which results in two or more rows (just one column) and I want to catch the first row value into first temp variable and second row value into second temp variable without using multiple times the select top 1 and select top 1 order by desc

Something like this;

```
Select row1 value into @tempvariable1, row2 value into @tempvariable2 from blah blah
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556097/how-do-i-set-a-temp-variable-to-a-value-based-from-another-table

Comment: Thanks @Zane about that suggestion/soln but, I am afraid it has got select top 1 which I want to avoid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need somehow to identify the row (I am using a row ID in the example below, ordering by value - you can order by id or something else):

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [value] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource
VALUES ('value 1')
      ,('value 2')
      ,('value 3');

DECLARE @tempVariable1 VARCHAR(12)
       ,@tempVariable2 VARCHAR(12);

WITH DataSource ([value], [rowID]) AS
(
    SELECT [value]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [value])
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT @tempVariable1 = IIF([rowID] = 1, [value], @tempVariable1)
      ,@tempVariable2 = IIF([rowID] = 2, [value], @tempVariable2)
FROM DataSource;

SELECT @tempVariable1
      ,@tempVariable2;
```

Comment: cheers @gotqn , the last but one select with iif condition helped me to tweak around my query and it did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE where you will get the X values you need and then select from it:

```
declare @data table(id int);
insert into @data(id) values(8), (6), (4), (3);

with vals(id, n) as (
    Select top(2) id, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id)
    From @data      
) 
Select @A = (Select id From vals Where n = 1)
    , @B = (Select id From vals Where n = 2)
```

You could also use PIVOT:

```
Select @A = [1], @B = [2]
From (
    Select id, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id)
    From @data
) v(id, n)
PIVOT (
    max(id) FOR n in ([1], [2])
) as piv
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

Let's say we test case is build as below

```
create table dbo.Test
(
   value varchar(100) not null
)

GO

insert into dbo.Test
values
('A'),('B'),('NO THIS ONE'),('NO THIS ONE'),('NO THIS ONE')

GO
```

Now let's say you fetch your data as below

```
select t.value
 from dbo.Test t
 where t.value != 'NO THIS ONE'
 GO
```

The first and easier option is to save the data in a temp table

```
  declare @results as Table (value varchar(100))

 insert into @results
 select t.value
 from dbo.Test t
 where t.value != 'NO THIS ONE'
```

you still use TOP 1 BUT not in the entire data, only in the results.

Use `TOP 1` to find the first result and a second `TOP 1` where value is different from the first.

```
declare @A varchar(100), @B varchar(100)

set @A = (select top 1 r.value from @results r)
set @B = (select top 1 r.value from @results r where r.value != @A)

select @A, @B
GO
```

This approach have the advantage of performance.
Of course that don't work great if **both values are equal**. You can fix it by using a `top 1` and ordering in the inverse order.

There's a **better alternative** using `rownumber`.
It works because if you set a variable when returning multiple rows the varible sticks with the last one (in fact it's reseted for each row iteration).

The **case statement** makes sure the variable `@A` is seted only on the first row iteration.

```
declare @A varchar(100), @B varchar(100)

/* This way @B receives the last value and @A the first */
select @B = t.value,
 @A = (case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by t.Value) = 1
 then t.Value else @A
 end)
 from dbo.Test t
 where t.value != 'NO THIS ONE'

 select @A, @B
```